# Открыть файл Sketch на Windows

Tags: photoshop

Ребят, как открыть `sketch`-формат на Windows? Есть программуля avocode, но там нужно ставить доп. плагин, который на [этой](https://manager.avocode.com/downloads/) странице у меня выдает только версию для OS X.

Answer (score 7):

Есть еще бесплатный сервис [lunacy](https://icons8.com/lunacy) Он работает оффлайн тоже

Comment: На движке Lunacy ещё выпущен онлайн вьювер http://sketch.the.ripper.graphics/

Answer (score 4):

На данный момент мне известны три популярных решения - [Avocode](https://avocode.com/), [Zeplin](https://zeplin.io/) и [Sympli](https://sympli.io/).

Лично работал только с Zeplin. Это веб-сервис (а с июня-июля 2016 - еще и webkit-based приложение, под windows), через который можно **делиться** работами в Sketch. Именно делиться, но не открывать sketch-файлы.

Работает это так:

- Автор sketch-макетов, c OS X, регистрируется в Zeplin и добавляет туда макеты
- Другие люди могут теперь заходить в Zeplin в аккаунт к автору макетов и просматривать их

Вероятно, вам нужно обратиться к автору макетов, с OS X на компьютере, и попросить его организовать вам доступ к его макетам в Zeplin (или аналогичном сервисе).

Comment: А другими двумя можно именно открыть файлы (не в курсе)?

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko, Кратко: **Avocode теперь может**. Подробно: Во всех случаях идет преобразование `.sketch` файлов в собственный формат сервиса. Все три сервиса используют для этого свои плагины для Sketch - с их помощью они открывают добавляемый файл в скетче, и через скетч получают структуру макета и параметры всех элементов. Работает это только в OS X, т..к. только на этой платформе есть скетч. Но, с недавних пор, Avocode позволяет загружать `.sketch` файлы им на сервер. И они будут обрабатывать его на их собственных серверах с OS X. Поэтому да, в Avocode можно добавлять файлы в любых ОС.

Comment: @ВиталийЕмельянцев , Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Помимо выше перечисленных есть еще [Figma](https://www.figma.com/), в котором можно импортировать .sketch файл и работать с ним.

Тут еще упоминали [Lunacy](https://icons8.com/lunacy), разработчики которого заявляют, что добавили поддержку нового формата файла Sketch 43.